# Underfull hbox warnings when using Siunitx

Tags: tcolorbox, siunitx, underfull

When using Siunitx package text I get underfull hbox warning (It stretches the text too much to my liking). Is there a way to limit how much streching my document makes? I would ideally want it to do a linebreak automatically, instead of stretching the text so much.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
%% Underfull hbox with tcolorbox 
\begin{tcolorbox}
    abcdefghijkl: Siroenen gallem tem oacamstyrade strqmelde iseaa \SI{2.25}{\mA}
    some more text
\end{tcolorbox}

 abcdefghijkl: Siroenen gallem tem oacamstyrade strqmelde iseaa \SI{2.25}{\mA}
    some more text

%% Overfull hbox
 abcdefghijkl: Siroenen gallem tem oaweweweeewwstyrade strqmelde iseaa \SI{2.25}{\mA}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    abcdefghijkl: Siroenen gallem tem oacamstyrade strqmelde iseaa \\ \SI{2.25}{\mA}
    some more text
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: How my document looks]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
 \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=left]
```

[image]